# Generate dynamic comments with sweet.js

Tags: javascript, sweet.js

How can I transform the following snippet:

```
let myVar: string = 'test';
```

To following output:

```
// type {string}
var myVar = 'test';
```

using sweetjs?

**UPDATE**

I'm looking for a way to transform the exact first code snippet to the second one. Including the `// type {string}` comment.

I Want to use it to create a simple DSL to generate a code to be checked with google closure compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
let let = macro {
    case { _ $name $[:] $type = $init:expr } => {
        var typeStr = unwrapSyntax(#{$type});
        var varStx = makeKeyword("var", #{here});
        varStx.token.leadingComments = [{
            type: "Line",
            value: " type {" + typeStr + "}"
        }];
        letstx $var = [varStx];
        return #{
            $var $name = $init
        }
    }
}
let myVar: string = 'test';
```

expands to:

```
// type {string}
var myVar = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but maybe this snippet:

```
macro m {
    case {_ () } => {
        var x = makeValue(0, #{here});
        x.token.leadingComments = [{
            type: "Line",
            value: " type {string}"
        }];
        return withSyntax ($x = [x]) #{
            $x
        }
    }
}
m()

macro foo {
  rule { $id = $init } => {
    var $id = $init
  }
  rule { $init } => { var myVar = $init }
}

foo "test";
```

Sadly you cannot output comments without having a token.

### OUTPUT

```
// type {string}
0;
var myVar = 'test';
```

Also check out [this](http://jlongster.com/Writing-Your-First-Sweet.js-Macro) page at heading "Hygiene", its around the 3/4 of the page.

Hope that helps.

### UPDATE

Read through some articles saying a simple rule macro should do the job:

```
macro foo {
  rule { $id = $init } => {
    var $id = $init
  }
  rule { $init } => { var myVar = $init }
}
// type {string}
foo "test";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not what I'm looking for. I want a way to transform the exact first code snippet to the second one. Including the `// type {string}` comment.

I Want to use it to create a simple DSL to generate a code to be checked by google closure. (OBS: Google clouse uses the comments to validate the type checking)

Comment: Exactly! Do you know how to generate this comment in the output?

Comment: @Diullei Well you can output comments via tokens, but you can't output only the comment as I see. It will output the token too. Wrokin' on it.

Comment: I saw this in the documentation. So, ok... thank you!